# Python: Regular expression to match alpha-numeric characters not working on LeetCode compiler

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is not working using this solution.

[image]

Leetcode question:
125. Valid Palindrome
Easy
8.6K
8.1K
Companies
A phrase is a palindrome if, after converting all uppercase letters into lowercase letters and removing all non-alphanumeric characters, it reads the same forward and backward. Alphanumeric characters include letters and numbers.

Given a string s, return true if it is a palindrome, or false otherwise.

Example 1:

Input: s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
Output: true
Explanation: "amanaplanacanalpanama" is a palindrome.
Example 2:

Input: s = "race a car"
Output: false
Explanation: "raceacar" is not a palindrome.
Example 3:

Input: s = " "
Output: true
Explanation: s is an empty string "" after removing non-alphanumeric characters.
Since an empty string reads the same forward and backward, it is a palindrome.

Constraints:

1 <= s.length <= 2 * 105
s consists only of printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Where did you learn that `_` is included in `\W`?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation indicates, \W matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so underscore is a valid word character.

It seems like you want `[^a-z]+`.